# OSX: `ping 127.0.0.1` fails with "No route to host"

Tags: routing, macos

When I am offline then  `ping 127.0.0.1` fails with "No route to host". How to troubleshoot that? I am running CloudFlare Warp, which could be messing up with routing (even though I switched it of, but without a restart). But I have no idea how to check that.

This explains why ping fails:

```
❯ netstat -rn
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Netif Expire
224.0.0            link#1             UmCS           lo0

Internet6: ...
```

with internet on, the route table inludes

```
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Netif Expire
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH             lo0
```

but the question why is it that way remains.

OSX: 11.6 Big Sur

#### Update

Disabling Warp and restarting fixed it (not sure whether both steps or only the restart were necessary). My routing table has 127... now:

```
❯ netstat -rn
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Netif Expire
default            192.168.0.1        UGScg          en0
127                127.0.0.1          UCS            lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH             lo0
...
```

re-enabling Warp and getting offline does not break it:

```
❯ netstat -rn
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Netif Expire
127                127.0.0.1          UCS            lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH             lo0
224.0.0            link#1             UmCS           lo0
224.0.0.251        link#1             UHmW3I         lo0   2398

Internet6:
...
```

Comment: What version of OSX

Comment: I have 11.6 Big Sur

Comment: So it's probably a bug in Cloudflare Warp... try filing a bug report.

Comment: I would have thought it's not routing you should be looking at, but what interfaces are seen. `netstat -i` should show loopback, `lo` up and running.

Comment: Thanks! lo is up and running